Finitely generated module over a skew Laurent polynomial ring $\mathbb{K}[x_1^{\pm 1},x_2^{\pm1}]$
Let $A := \mathbb{K}_{\Lambda}[x_1^{\pm 1}, x_2^{\pm 1}, x_3^{\pm 1}, x_4^{\pm 1}]$, $B := \mathbb{K}_{\Lambda'}[x_1^{\pm 1}, x_2^{\pm 1}, x_3^{\pm 1}]$, and $C := \mathbb{K}_{\Lambda''}[x_1^{\pm 1}, x_2^{\pm 1}]$ be skew-Laurent polynomial rings.
Consider the element $f = x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 + 1$ in $A$ and the right $A$-module $A / fA$. Since $f$ is unitary over $B$, the right $A$-module $A / fA$ is finitely generated over the skew Laurent polynomial ring $B$.
Is the right $A$-module $A / fA$ also finitely generated over the skew  Laurent polynomial ring $C$?

These look like ordinary Laurent polynomial rings to me. Do you want some parameters?

@J.Gaddis yes we can assume that no parameters are roots of unity.
